# Passing array into a constructor and getting "cannot convert double[] to int" error

Tags: java, arrays, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass a simple array into a constructor of a class and kept getting a "cannot convert double[] to int" error. I'm really lost as to why.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] data = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
        Rainfall[] rain = new Rainfall[data];   
    }
}


import java.util.*;

public class Rainfall {
    private double[] monthlyRain;

    public Rainfall(double [] array) {
        monthlyRain = array;
    }
}
```

My IDE kept showing a red squiggly line underneath the "data" in

```
Rainfall[] rain = new Rainfall[data];
```

in the main method.

Comment: ``Rainfall rain = new Rainfall(data)`` You need to use parentheses rather than brackets. Also, a constructor can only create a single object.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead...you are invoking constructor wrongly... with `Rainfall[] rain = new Rainfall[data];`

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] data = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
        // Rainfall[] rain = new Rainfall[data];   wrong...
           Rainfall[] rain = new Rainfall[]{new Rainfall(data) }; // correct
    }
}
```

The thing is... `Rainfal[]` only holds an array of `Rainfall` objects...not one..
So thats..the correct way...sorry for error...

Comment: `Rainfall[] rain = new Rainfall(data)`.. It is not correct you cannot assign instance of class to an array of class

Comment: Sorry..i missed the `[]` on rainfall but the mistake is...you are constructing wrongly...check the edit....

Comment: The `Rainfall[]` is a group of `Rainfall` objects(array)...thats why am assigning it to another `Rainfall[]{}`

Comment: @EurekaMark almost certainly intends to have only a single `Rainfall`, which contains an array for the months, and therefore should just have `Rainfall rainfall = new Rainfall(data)`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-  Thank you very much. Your answer was very helpful, and I see where my logic is off.